# Wordpress navigation crashes - PHP errors

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site running a free theme called '**Workality Lite'**. Recently after doing some updates to the site and updating all plug-ins and themes the site randomly crashes when navigating from page to page. The error message I get is :

> *Not Found The requested URL /blindness-depending.php was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. Apache Server at
>   www.vfxofsbn.com Port 80*

It seemed there was something to do with the PHP, so I tried to update the PHP version on my hosting platform (GoDaddy) from 5.3 to 5.4 but that didn't seem to to anything.

Anyone have any thoughts as to what causes the problem ? Keep in mind I don't know much about code so preferably keep it in lame-man terms.

Much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its permalinks problem,

First make sure that your sub pages are working with default permalinks

go to settings->permalinks

choose "default" and save and try to navigate, if this is working fine then

replace the .htaccess code with this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and revert back the permalink structure to which ever structure you want,

Best thing is choose "Postname" in permalinks

Comment: Yes, that fixed it ! Thank you very much !